# Asking for a fix for R backtick operator

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to import data from in xls format in R, but it reads the header incorrectly, instead of

```
X1
```

R interprets the data as

```
`X1 `
```

that makes writing complicated R syntax impossible.

How this issue can be resolved ?

Comment: welcome to SO. you were prompted to write a detailed, reproducible example when you started a question. You've also likely read many SO questions & shld be able to tell good ones from bad ones. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example has info on how to make a gd question.

Comment: Having said ^^, why not just change the column names after you read in the xls file? `?colnames` in an R console will show you how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

One can skip the header record and give your own column names with any number of R packages that read excel data. Here is an example with `readxl::read_excel()`.

```
library(readxl)
data <- read_excel("./data/anExcelWorksheet.xlsx",
                   col_names=FALSE,
                   skip=1)
```

Comment: Actually, the problem was solved after installing the most recent update of R

Comment: @Idomen which package and function did you use to read the data?

Comment: I am using no package, just I load .xlsx file, I use attach command for dataset and I type the name of the variable.

Comment: @Idomen please update your original post to include the exact code you used to read the file. How did you "load the .xlsx file?"

Comment: @Igleski Just I  used the drop-down menu from Import dataset button,